# Elemento NO responde a evento click

Tags: javascript, html, css

tengo un pequeño problema.
Estoy teniendo problemas con la función addEventListener. El caso es que quiero que se ejecute un setInterval tras hacer clic en un input, pero cuando lo hago, no ocurre nada. Este es el código JavaScript y HTML.

```js
const action_on = document.getElementById("customRange1");
action_on.addEventListener('click', function() {
  setInterval(() => {
    const value_input = document.getElementById("customRange1").value;
    const value_text = document.getElementById("first-label");
    value_text.innerText = value_input + " Minutos";
  }, 100);
})
```

```html
<label for="customRange1" class="form-label first-label"> Tiempo Actividad </label>
<input type="range" class="form-range" min="0" max="60" step="1" id="customRange1">
<p id="first-label"></p>
```

Me doy cuenta de que en el intérprete de stackoverflow funciona correctamente. Pero cuando lo pruebo en mi proyecto no funciona correctamente.

Comment: ¿y ya has revisado en la consola si aparece algún error de javascript que esté impidiendo su funcionamiento en tu proyecto?  Para ello pulsa F12 en tu navegador, vete a la pestaña Consola y recarga la página y repite la acción.  Sino te sale nada quizás es que estás duplicando ids y espera la acción en otro distinto al que estás probando.

Comment: No, no hay error en consola. Tampoco tengo ids repetidos

Comment: Pues ponle algún console.log() dentro del addEventListener para ver si al menos entra en la función al darle al click y así delimitar mejor el problema

Comment: Acabo de hacerlo, y no. No esta entrando en la funcion.

Comment: je, eso me temia... pues no se, sin más contexto poco más podemos hacer por aquí, lo siento... juega con el console.log() en otras partes de tu código a ver si lo puedes ir siguiendo y detectar donde aún funciona y donde no

Comment: Lo raro es que, como ya mencione, en el intérprete de Stackoverflow funciona.

Comment: será porque has hecho un [example] perfecto sin errores, pero en tu proyecto quizás hay interferencias con otros códigos de javascript por lo que sea... usas bootstrap por ejemplo?

Comment: Acabo de ver cuál es el error. Parece ser el navegador. En Edge no funciona, pero lo acabo de probar en Chrome y funciona bien ;-;

Comment: vaya, pues no se, no uso ni windous ni edge y no puedo ayudarte a reproducir el error... ponlo en la pregunta y borramos comentarios para no asustar a quien lo sepa :-)

Comment: que esta pasandoooooooo, cerré y abrí de nuevo Edge y ahora funciona bien :D

Comment: vaya, la solución informática a todo... **apaga y vuelve a encender** :-)  pues nada, ya está, solucionado!  Saludos!! :-D

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda :D

Answer (score 2):

Al parecer es un error del navegador, probe en otros navegadores y funciona correctamente. Luego entonces cerré y abri de nuevo el navegador en el que estaba trabajando y todo funciona bien.

Comment: Cuando hagas cambios grandes tanto en JS como en CSS te recomiendo que a la hora de refrescar la web uses o bien Ctrl+R o bien Shift+F5, para así borrar el cache del navegador, otra manera es o bien como has hecho, cambiando de navegador o bien entrando en el modo incognito.
sino muchos navegadores te permiten refrescar la página borrando cache